# Can you set "\t" tab to always be the same size in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea, which I am trying to insert tabs of the same size into.

As you can see in the example, the only difference in each line of the `testString` is the position of the `\t`.

However, in the resulting textarea, the size of the tabs are different, seemingly dependent on how many characters are in front of it. This causes text after the tab to not be aligned properly.

In my perfect world, all of the 5s in the textarea would be aligned vertically, since each line is technically the same (five characters + one tab)

I am aware of the CSS property `tab-size`, and though this indeed changes the size of tabs, the resulting tab size in the textarea is still based on how many characters are in front of it.

I don't want to insert spaces rather than tabs, because I want a single backspace/delete to remove the entire tab, but if someone enters multiple spaces in succession, I would like backspace/delete to only clear single spaces as per usual.

Is there something that I am missing? Are there any workarounds to achieve this? My research has returned no helpful results, so I am now reaching out here.

Thanks for your help.

```js
testString = '1\t2345' + '\n' + '12\t345' + '\n' + '123\t45' + '\n' + '1234\t5'
document.getElementById('text').value = testString
```

```html
<textarea cols="10" rows="4" id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: Are you using a fixed width Font?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's how tabs are supposed to work in ASCII.

Comment: @NickSlash Yes, this happens with monospaced fonts

Comment: @user1280483 So are you saying that what I am trying to achieve is impossible?

Comment: @gbac How would one enter a tab in the first place?

Comment: @skara9 I've set an event listener that inserts \t at the cursor position when a specific key is pressed

Comment: @Alohci Is it possible to change that behavior?

Comment: Not that I can think of. There's various size width spaces in Unicode, but not one of arbitrary size. At a pinch, you could patch a font to contain a space character width of whatever width you wanted, I guess.

Comment: @Alohci That's a neat idea, but won't work for my application because copying the text to clipboard will not retain the tab size. I appreciate your creative response though.

Answer (score 1):

You can get close to the requested outcome in case your use-case is in fact just having single type of "wide general white-space separators" that are not aligned at tab stops in your textarea. CSS `white-space: pre-line` strips tabs their "tab-stops" obeying behaviour and makes all spaces and tabs collapse to single words separating unit. Width of these "units" can be adjusted with `word-spacing`:

```html
<p contenteditable role="textbox"
 style="
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-spacing: 1em;
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
 ">
4×Space:
1    2345
12    345
123    45
1234    5

1×Space:
1 2345
12 345
123 45
1234 5

1×Tab:
1   2345
12  345
123 45
1234    5

»&ensp;« (ensp)
»&emsp;« (emsp)
»&#x3000;« (IDEOGRAPHIC)
» « (space)
»&#x0009;« (tab)
</p>
```

As demonstrated, it works for given example. Drawbacks are that:

- several spaces in cluster are rendered as one, what would be probably confusing for editors,
- it strips a way to enter "normally looking" space to the text easily: for "narrow / normally looking" space one would have to use for example `&ensp;` instead (see bottom of above snippet).

Edit: realized that using `contenteditable` instead of `textarea` brings few extra aspects (own different drawbacks) into play, especially with regard to inserting white space.  Here is same styling applied to real `textarea` to try editing experience with drawbacks described earlier:

```html
<textarea rows="25"
 style="
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-spacing: 1em;
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
 ">
4×Space:
1    2345
12    345
123    45
1234    5

1×Space:
1 2345
12 345
123 45
1234 5

1×Tab:
1   2345
12  345
123 45
1234    5

»&ensp;« (ensp)
»&emsp;« (emsp)
»&#x3000;« (IDEOGRAPHIC)
» « (space)
»&#x0009;« (tab)
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Unfortunately, this won't work for my actual use-case due to the mentioned drawbacks, however, this has been very informative, and I do appreciate it.

Comment: Yes I thought it will not be usable. Anyway, if your use case involves necessity for two kinds of separators and if you are already "augmenting" input of tabs, you could hypothetically augment regular spaces in a similar manner, effectively remapping tab key to insert tab (or even regular space) and spacebar to actually insert `&ensp;`.  (Yes, it sounds scary and seems like a footgun, but (besides rolling own font with custom special space) seems like the only option to me.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I was thinking along those lines, but I want to retain the correct spacing when copying to clipboard or saving to text file, which doesn't seem to be possible with either workaround because the spacing relies on either CSS or a custom font. Honestly, I figured this was a long shot when posting the question, but I just wasn't happy with my research results and hoped that there might be another way that I was missing.